# Android Kotlin - Facebook Login - get user data

Tags: android, kotlin, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm new in android developement and already searched for hours without finding the way how to get the damn user data after facebook login!

This is the code:

```
private var callbackManager: CallbackManager? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fb_connect)




        // Login
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"))
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
                    override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
                        Log.d("letsSee", "Facebook token: " + loginResult.accessToken.token)

                    }

                    override fun onCancel() {
                        Log.d("letsSee", "Facebook onCancel.")

                    }

                    override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
                        Log.d("letsSee", "Facebook onError.")

                    }
                })

}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    callbackManager?.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    Log.d("letsSee", "malsehnnnnnn: " + data)
}
```

The `Log.d("letsSee", "malsehnnnnnn: " + data)` at the bottom gives: `malsehnnnnnn: Intent { (has extras) }`

Where is the damn data???? The facebook docs are weird and very poor!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Send GraphRequest usign `accessToken` and you will get json of your requested fields.

**Updated into kotlin**

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
        override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
            Logger.d("FBLOGIN", loginResult.accessToken.token.toString())
            Logger.d("FBLOGIN", loginResult.recentlyDeniedPermissions.toString())
            Logger.d("FBLOGIN", loginResult.recentlyGrantedPermissions.toString())


            val request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.accessToken) { `object`, response ->
                try {
                    //here is the data that you want
                    Logger.d("FBLOGIN_JSON_RES", `object`.toString())

                    if (`object`.has("id")) {
                        handleSignInResultFacebook(`object`)
                    } else {
                        Logger.e("FBLOGIN_FAILD", `object`.toString())
                    }

                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    dismissDialogLogin()
                }
            }

            val parameters = Bundle()
            parameters.putString("fields", "name,email,id,picture.type(large)")
            request.parameters = parameters
            request.executeAsync()

        }

        override fun onCancel() {
            Logger.e("FBLOGIN_FAILD", "Cancel")
        }

        override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
            Logger.e("FBLOGIN_FAILD", "ERROR", error)
        }
    })
```

**Old answer**

Here is the java code working for me

```
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Logger.d("FBLOGIN", String.valueOf(loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()));
            Logger.d("FBLOGIN", String.valueOf(loginResult.getRecentlyDeniedPermissions().toString()));
            Logger.d("FBLOGIN", String.valueOf(loginResult.getRecentlyGrantedPermissions().toString()));


            final GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    try {
                        //here is the data that you want
                        Logger.d("FBLOGIN_JSON_RES", String.valueOf(object));

                        if (object.has("id")) {
                            handleSignInResultFacebook(object);
                        } else {
                            Logger.e("FBLOGIN_FAILD", String.valueOf(object));
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        dismissDialogLogin();
                    }
                }
            });

            final Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "name,email,id,picture.type(large)");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Logger.e("FBLOGIN_FAILD", "Cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Logger.e("FBLOGIN_FAILD", "ERROR", error);
        }
    });
```

convert into kotlin

Comment: He has asked how to do it in kotlin. Please post it in kotlin.

Comment: @ManojPerumarath: I have updated the answer with kotlin code

Comment: The app stopps running with this code and I don't get any errors. Maybe because I use the latest Facebook SDK 4.35.0 ? I tried to use 4.0 but can't, it breaks other libraries

Comment: Also there was unsolved reference: handleSignInResultFacebook so I commented it out, I don't know what else to do here

Comment: Ok now I just added what's inside onSuccess to my previous code and it worked, thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

The accepted gives me an error in **Kotlin** of `Interface GraphJSONObjectCallback does not have constructors`

This slightly modified version of the `GraphRequest.newMeRequest` worked for me.

```
  LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this@MainActivity, Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"))

  LoginManager.getInstance()
    .registerCallback(mCallbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
      override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {

        val token = loginResult.accessToken

        val request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
          token,
          object : GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback {
            override fun onCompleted(
              obj: JSONObject?,
              response: GraphResponse?
            ) {

              try {
                // Save user email to variable
                email = obj!!.getString("email")
                firstName = obj.getString("first_name")
                lastName = obj.getString("last_name")
                Log.d(TAG, "1) Facebook email received $email and name $firstName $lastName")
                handleFacebookAccessToken(token)
              }
              catch (e: JSONException) {
                Toast.makeText(
                  this@MainActivity,
                  "Facebook Authentication Failed.",
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
              }
            }
          })

        val parameters = Bundle()
        parameters.putString("fields", "email,first_name,last_name")
        request.parameters = parameters
        request.executeAsync()
      }

      override fun onCancel() {
        Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel")
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Facebook Login Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
      }

      override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
        Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error)
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Facebook Authentication Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
          .show()
      }
    })
```